cpu_type_t and cpu_subtype_t — definitions
From man open:
 --arch ARCH
     Launch with the given cpu architecture type and subtype; ARCH should be one of
     any, arm, arm64, arm64e, arm64_32, x86_64, x86_64h, i386.  Two integers
     matching the values for cpu_type_t and cpu_subtype_t can be specified as
     integers separated by a '/' character, like "12/13" for
     CPU_TYPE_ARM/CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V8.

The 12/13 suggests that there may exist 1→11 values for cpu_type_t and cpu_subtype_t.  Where would I find a list, and what other uses do they have?
Related: `open --arch ARCH` works on the wrong processor?

They are defined in the kernel sources, specifically in machine.h.
#define CPU_TYPE_ANY            ((cpu_type_t) -1)

#define CPU_TYPE_VAX            ((cpu_type_t) 1)
/* skip             ((cpu_type_t) 2)    */
/* skip             ((cpu_type_t) 3)    */
/* skip             ((cpu_type_t) 4)    */
/* skip             ((cpu_type_t) 5)    */
#define CPU_TYPE_MC680x0        ((cpu_type_t) 6)
#define CPU_TYPE_X86            ((cpu_type_t) 7)
#define CPU_TYPE_I386           CPU_TYPE_X86            /* compatibility */
#define CPU_TYPE_X86_64         (CPU_TYPE_X86 | CPU_ARCH_ABI64)

/* skip CPU_TYPE_MIPS       ((cpu_type_t) 8)    */
/* skip                         ((cpu_type_t) 9)    */
#define CPU_TYPE_MC98000        ((cpu_type_t) 10)
#define CPU_TYPE_HPPA           ((cpu_type_t) 11)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM            ((cpu_type_t) 12)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM64          (CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM64_32       (CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64_32)
#define CPU_TYPE_MC88000        ((cpu_type_t) 13)
#define CPU_TYPE_SPARC          ((cpu_type_t) 14)
#define CPU_TYPE_I860           ((cpu_type_t) 15)
/* skip CPU_TYPE_ALPHA      ((cpu_type_t) 16)   */
/* skip             ((cpu_type_t) 17)   */
#define CPU_TYPE_POWERPC                ((cpu_type_t) 18)
#define CPU_TYPE_POWERPC64              (CPU_TYPE_POWERPC | CPU_ARCH_ABI64)



Also in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach/machine.h, if Xcode is installed.

So this is a Free BSD thing and not an Apple thing.  Covers chips Apple has never used.

The file is part of the Mach kernel.
